# Find all polynomials such that $P(x)\in \Bbb{ Z}\implies x\in \Bbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Find all polynomials such that $$P(x)\in \Bbb{ Z}\implies x\in \Bbb{Z}$$

Consider $P(x)=0\implies P(x)$ has integer roots only. Hence $$P(x)=a(x-a_1)\dots(x-a_n).$$

Let $Q(x)= (x-a_1)\dots(x-a_n).$ If $a\ne 1$ then $P(x)=1\implies Q(x)=\frac{1}{a}\implies x\not \in \Bbb{Z}.$ As $Q(x)$ has integer coefficients.

Hence $P(x)=Q(x)$ is an integer polynomial. Moreover, $P(x)= y \implies x\in \Bbb{Z}~\forall y \in \Bbb{Z}$

Also, since $P(x)$ is an integer polynomial, we get that $\forall a,b, a-b|P(a)-P(b)$

Any solutions?

Comment: You can easily show that all coefficients of $P(x)$ have to be rational numbers by looking at system of $n$ equations i.e. picking $n$ values of $P(x)$ which are in $Z$. On the other hand, it is easy to check that $P(x) = 1/2 + 1/2 x$ has also required property.

Comment: Looks like you implicitly assumed $a$ was an integer in your argument, but as @salcio's example shows, and your own argument as well, $a$ can be the reciprocal of an integer.

Comment: @Cheerful No, once again if the polynomial is not constant it takes on n values in $Z$, say $z_1,z_2,...z_n$. We know that for each $i$ there is $x_i$ in $Z$ such that $P(x_i)= z_i$. So you can write system of $n$ linear equations for the polynomial coefficients and its solution (via inverse matrix) are rational.

Comment: @Salcio I already showed P(x) must be an integer poly. Or did I do something wrong? Please help.

Comment: Well, reconsider your proof. $1/2 + 1/2x$ does it

Comment: @salcio I am not sure how your comment applies to me. To the OP, your proof looks fine *except* that you assumed $a$ was an integer. So $P(x)$ it is not necessarily an integer polynomial. However, your proof does show that $a$ is the reciprocal of an integer. Still work to be done though to get a final characterization.

Comment: @Cheerful Somehow, I thought you were commenting on my comment ... Sorry for the mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the summary is that the only such polynomials are linear polynomials $p(x)=\frac{1}{m}(x-n)$ for some integers $m,n$. You can verify these work. To rule out higher degree polynomials, @Ho-Oh's idea is to consider $p(n)-p(n-1)$ for large values of $n$. Eventually this difference will exceed $1$ in absolute value, so by the intermediate value theorem, there will be some $n<x<n+1$ such that $p(x)$ is an integer.

You can also have constant non-integer polynomials which vacuously satisfy the criterion.

Answer (score 9):

Hint: If $deg(P)\ge2$, then when $x$ is large the polynomial will grow too fast that a tiny bit change in $x$ makes $P(x)$ encounter an integer.

Comment: +1. If deg$(P)\ge 2$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}|P(x+1)-P(x)|=\infty$ so there exists $n\in\Bbb N$ with $|P(n+1)-P(n)|>2$ and for this $n$ there exists $y\in (n,n+1)$ with $P(y)\in\Bbb Z.$